# Pandas Date(column) to int conversion, in a Large database

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

**I am using Jupyter notebook and Pandas**

I have a large CSV file in python. with a column called date with dates in YYYY-MM-DD format.
Is there any way to convert all the days into integers?

Meaning: I want to subtract a date(ex: 2020.01.01) from all the dates and get a simple integer as the days. And replace the dates with integers.

I've tried for some time but can't think of a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can compute for each date the number of days from a reference date:

```py
ref_date = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2021')

df['int_day'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.Date) - ref_date).dt.days
```

If your column is already in a Datetime format:

```py
df['int_day'] = (df.Date - ref_date).dt.days
```

Here an example (with 'Date' column of `str` type):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range('1/1/2021', '1/15/2021', freq='D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    columns=['Date']
)

ref_date = pd.to_datetime('1/1/2021')

df['int_day'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.Date) - ref_date).dt.days
```

Here the DataFrame `df`:

```sh
          Date  int_day
0   2021-01-01        0
1   2021-01-02        1
2   2021-01-03        2
3   2021-01-04        3
4   2021-01-05        4
5   2021-01-06        5
6   2021-01-07        6
7   2021-01-08        7
8   2021-01-09        8
9   2021-01-10        9
10  2021-01-11       10
11  2021-01-12       11
12  2021-01-13       12
13  2021-01-14       13
14  2021-01-15       14
```

Answer (score 0):

If date column is parsed to timestamp

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
```

If it is not parsed

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('-', '').astype(int)
```